# How to convert a PyObject to string in C#

Tags: python, c#, python.net, pyobject

I am working with Pythonnet to create a C# GUI that uses backend Python code.  I am just learning how the connection works and need to get a Python variable into C# and display it in a C# text box.  How can I get the value computed for 'outer' in Python and display it in the textBox1?  It works fine when sending the output to a console but I need it in the text box.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python312-32\python312.dll";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //THIS WORKS NOW!!
            PyModule scope;


            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            using (Py.GIL())
            {

                scope = Py.CreateScope();
                //scope.Exec("print('Hello World from Python!')");

                dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
                dynamic outer=(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

                //This is the part that does not work.  
                //It says can't convert a PyObject to a string.
                textBox1.Text = outer  





                //Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: `outer.ToString()`?

Comment: outer.ToString() won't work because it is a Numpy object not a C# object.  It gives the following error: "Python.Runtime.PythonException: ''numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'ToString''"

Comment: Try `Py.Import("builtins").str(...);`